# Convert a Dictionary<string,string> data structure to a 2D string array data structure

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm using an in house Automation Framework that runs on Unity.
My goal is to create an email report service.

I'm using a dictionary to store the automation name as key and the status (pass/fail) as value.

After running all the automation test I want to send an email report with all the data, as an HTML table. There is a service that created an HTML table but need a 2D string array.

Is there a way to convert the `Dictionary<string,string>` data structure to a 2D string array data structure?

Comment: Show the input and output. Stories are not very concise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        dictionary.Add("key1", "value1");
        dictionary.Add("key2", "value2");
        dictionary.Add("key3", "value3");

        var arrayFromDictionary = ConvertDictionaryTo2DArray(dictionary);
    }

    static string[,] ConvertDictionaryTo2DArray(Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
    {
        var count = dictionary.Count;
        var arr = new string[count, 2];
        var index = 0;
        foreach (var item in dictionary)
        {
            arr[index, 0] = item.Key;
            arr[index, 1] = item.Value;
            index++;
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```